# Number one in mathbb environment with MathTime Pro 2 Complete Fonts (PCTeXv6)

Tags: fonts, mathcal

I have got MathTime Pro 2 in PCTeXv6 (I use Windows 7) and the head of the document is:

[Tex Document](http://es.sharelatex.com/project/57a9c5b104d12705054952da)

I want to write the unity matrix with `\mathcal{1}`, exactly as this one : [image]

but **not** as that : [image]

even if they look similar. This is a minimal working example (MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[complete,mtphrb,slantedGreek,zswash,subscriptcorrection]{mtpro2}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\text{De la condición } A^\dagger A =\mathcal{1}\text{ se sigue}\]
\end{document}
```

There is an error when I use *amssymb* package (I think that it's in contradiction with other packages).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You will learn how to embed pictures in your question, as well as markdown formatting (e.g., using backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit). When providing code, please embed it in your question... but as a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) only!

Comment: (1)  is unity and  is unitary.  (2) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  The document in the link you posted is way too convoluted and complex to be of any use.  Also it tells me that there is a compile error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because is this question leaved?